# Expected number of days during 22 - day period of getting no 10 dollar bill

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have a problem with this question:
An ATM dispenses bank notes of 10, 20 , 50 and 100. The number
of 10 bills withdrawn on a given day is a random variable from a Poisson distribution with
parameter 18, if it is Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday or Friday and a Poisson distribution
with parameter 32/5, if it is Saturday or Sunday. We count the number of days between December
1st and 22nd of 2020 (inclusive), when no $10 bills are withdrawn. How many such days,
on average, will there be during this period?

What I've done so far was calculating the probability that there will be no 10 bills during the period of 1st Dec till 22nd Dec. Since both random variables come from a Poisson distribution i calculated P(X=0 successes) = e^-18 for getting no 10 bill during the weekdays and P(X=0) = e^-32/5.
Then I'm not sure about this part - I calculated a product of probabilities that we won't get $10 bills neither during weekdays nor at weekends which is e^-18 * e^-32/5 = e^-24.4
Then, to calculate the expected number of days during this 22 day period, I denoted that as N which comes from a binomial distribution with parameters 22 and e^-24.4
And to calculate the expected value of N, this is just np = 22*e^-24.4 = 5.5672064 * 10^-10. Which seems very odd.

Is my reasoning wrong? Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: I couldn't really follow your calculation, but the answer is clearly near $0$, though not as small as you claim.  We can effectively ignore weekdays and there are $6$ weekend days, so the answer should be about $e^{-32/5}\times 6\approx .01$.

Comment: sorry if i made my calculations unclear. But why can we ignore weekdays?

Comment: Because $e^{-18}$ is so small.  You don't need to ignore weekdays, but they are irrelevant.  There are $16$ weekdays in the period so the expected number of $\$10-$free weekdays is $e^{-18}\times 16\approx 2.44\times 10^{-7}$ which is negligible compared to $.01$